# How to set max line length rules in view? (not linting)

Tags: webstorm

I am using Webstorm 7 and want to set a max line length in the view to be 80 and not 120 (as the default ruler is set to).

I've searched all over and the closest I can find is the JSLinter (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/jslint.html) but I cannot seem to see how to actually change the ruler in the IDE.

Question: How do I set the ruler for the line length in Webstorm 7?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Settings > Editor > Code style > Hard wrap at [...] columns** (default is 120)

Comment: This is the path for linux version. Other OS' can differ.

Answer (score 12):

Quite late to the party and wrong version of Webstorm. But I got sent here by Google and in latest Webstorm (version 10) this option has been moved to Preferences > Editor > Code style - Right margin (columns).

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Just open Webstorm's settings and look for "right margin", this is quite quickly visible.

Answer (score 4):

The location to set the line length changed again.
March 2018 - PHPStorm 2017.3:
*Update: Still valid in 2021 for PhpStorm 2021.2.2*:

**Settings > Editor > Code style - Hard wrap at || Visual guides**

If the ruler doesn't show up at all, check that it is enabled:
**Settings > Editor > General > Appearance - Show hard wrap guide**

Answer (score 2):

It's November 21, 2017 ... I'm using WebStorm 2017.3 EAP and it's now called "hard wrap guide."

Editor / General / Appearance -> Show hard wrap guide.

[image: WebStorm hard wrap guide]